# Некорректно отрабатывает label на мобильной версии

Tags: css, адаптивность

**Есть сайт:** 
http://unilab.su/useful/calendar/pervyy-trimestr/

**На сайте есть подобная конструкция:**

```
    <div class="demo">
      <input type="checkbox" id="hd-1" class="hide">
      <label for="hd-1">
        <u>title</u>
      </label>
      <div>
      <p>
        lorem, lorem, lorem, lorem, lorem, lorem, 
        lorem, lorem, lorem, lorem.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Которая отвечает за аккордеон меню, вся логика написана на css. 
При клике на label, активируется checkbox, как только чекбокс активирован, 
При помощи селектора ".hide:checked + label + div" задаются св-ва.

На десктопной версии все отрабатывает корректно, ***но на мобильной отрабатывает через двойной клик по элементу (то есть вообще не отрабатывает, так как вместо активации чекбокса происходит выделение текста).***

Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: вас не смущает что есть ошибка в консоли `Игнорирование метода "preventDefault () 'на событие типа" touchstart "из функции-слушателя как" passive ".` в строке файла `custom.css` строка 471 добавьте `touch-action: none;` Возможно ошибаюсь но при двойном клике работает

Comment: @klifort, спасибо попробую